# Initialize a dictionary where each item is a list of empty unique lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm terribly sorry if this was already asked, but while I could find something similar I didn't find my specific issue. I have Python 3.7.4 - 64 bit. Basically I want to initialize a dictionary where each element is a list of empty lists. The problem is that in the way I'm doing it now I get that every single empty sub-list from the different items' list is the same object even though I am assigning a copy of the list to each item. As you can see in the code below, each sub-list in `empty_list_of_lists` is a different object. Then I assign the items to the dictionary as a copy of `empty_list_of_lists`. When I call `my_dict['a'] is my_dict['b']` I get an expected `False`, but when I call `my_dict['a'][0] is my_dict['b'][0]` I get a `True` which puzzles me because `empty_list_of_lists[0] is empty_list_of_lists[1]` returns `False` and I don't get the logic. How should I go about that?

Here is my code:

```
empty_list_of_lists = [[] for i in range(5)]

print(empty_list_of_lists[0] is empty_list_of_lists[1]) # returns False --> expected

dict1 = {'a': empty_list_of_lists.copy(), 'b': empty_list_of_lists.copy()}

print(dict1['a'] is dict1['b'])  # returns False --> expected
print(dict1['a'][0] is dict1['b'][0])  # returns True --> What?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
dict1 = {'a': [[] for _ in range(5)], 'b': [[] for _ in range(5)]}
```

or you can use `copy.deepcopy`

```
import copy

dict1 = {'a': copy.deepcopy(empty_list_of_lists), 'b': copy.deepcopy(empty_list_of_lists)}
```

you can read more about shallow and deep copy operations [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html)

in your code you are using a shallow copy but what you need a deep copy, from the above docs:

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
>   extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>   the original.
>
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
>   inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Comment: I was about to answer my own question because I found out about `deepcopy` just a minute ago! Thank you for the quick answer anyway, I didn't find it before because I thought it was a feature of dictionaries so I always included "dictionary" in my google search. Apologies for that